# Creating a python GUI with on/off switch

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a UI where in there are three indicator lights, Green, Yellow and Red where each has a switch on and off

then everytime a switch is turned on or turned off, it will create a csv log indicating the timestamp when a light was on or off, then individual columns for green, yellow, red light and it should log 0 (zero) when light is off then 1 (one) when a light is turned on

is that possible using tkinter? thank you so much!

Comment: Of course yes for your case.  Use `Label` as the indicators by setting its background color to indicate ON/OFF state.  Use `Checkbutton` as the switch ON/OFF button and assign its command function to toggle the indicators (setting the background of the indicators).  Saving indicators status should be just simple file write operation.

Comment: thank you so much! I willt try this and get back here if it works for me. :)